# Angular Material cdkDragFreeDragPosition error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

When I add `[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]` to a div I get the following error:

[image]

I tried to apply this same example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxalqlqlaly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.ts

Example:

```html
<div class="example-box" cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary" cdkDrag [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition">
  <h2>Test</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **DragDropModule** in NgModule. After that only drag drop will work. Please refer this link for more information. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: I am importing DragDropModule into my NgModule, and the drag drop function works, but when I add [cdkDragFreeDragPosition] to determine a position the error occurs.

Comment: @GabrielDambroski If you remove [cdkDragFreeDragPosition] then its working fine? and have you added dragPosition variable in ts file?

Comment: right when I remove [cdkDragFreeDragPosition] it works normally, my .ts file exists variable dragPosition = {x: 50, y: 50};

Comment: hi @GabrielDambroski have you resolved this issue?!